# How to easily import XML into rails(activerecord) database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Looking for modules and docs to read about importing xml documents into rails.

What I want to be able to.do.is have a persistent directory to have xml.files put into. Files will be same xml structure. I want files to be easily or automatically updated into the database.

Can I do this with ruby on rails with activercord?

Comment: You will find you answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369911/importing-an-xml-document-into-a-rails-database

Comment: @TomHert       thanks I had already seen that it shows basic info on working with Nokogiri but no info on managing or inserting into rails models consistently which is what my question is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. When/how to execute process:**

**Rake task that sync files with DB and exits**

Create a rake task that scans through your persistent directory and updates the database.  The rake task can be executed manually, or added as a cron job to the system.  You can load the rails environment by declaring a task with `task :sync => :environment do`.

**Rake task that keeps running**
You could use a gem such as [listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) to detect file changes to this directory and sync them to the DB.  Or your rake task could sleep for a few minutes internally.  You could also make this task a system service by creating a [upstart job](https://serverfault.com/questions/327965/how-to-start-a-rake-task-using-upstart).

**Background job library**

Use a job library such as [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) with [resque-scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler).

**2. Code structure**

I suggest the rake task/background job only serves as a mechanism to kick off the sync process.  Your actual syncing logic/code should still be in normal ruby classes/modules.

**3. How to perform xml -> db sync**

If you can dictate what the xml looks like, I recommend using activerecord [to_xml](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_xml) and [from_xml](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/from_xml) to export/create/update or have a look what they do internally (attributes= method).

If you can not dictate the format, use nokogiri or xmlsimple as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369911/importing-an-xml-document-into-a-rails-database) to parse the xml files.  Then use the normal active record querying/creating/updating methods to update the database.  Use activerecord validations to make sure your data is always consistent in the database.  If you want to make sure that no one can insert invalid data with other database connectors (not active record), you could use [database indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449459/how-to-make-column-unique-and-index-it-in-rails-migration).